# Problem in installing handlebar npm package in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I have tried to install the package but it is showing a lot of vulnerabilities and I cannot fix it properly even after using npm audit fix
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSvbm.png)

Comment: I see a package-lock.json file in the root of your folder but no package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it for your personal projects then no need to worry about the vulnerabilities and all. The packages have already been installed in your projects.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.